Can I load an external YAML file in a Quarto document?
I'd like to have a standardized set of yaml parameters for future quarto documents. For maintenance purposes, I'd like to avoid setting the parameters in each individual file. And I want to let the end user only need to modify the title of their document, and not worry about copying over all the other yaml header information.
How can I include the sample yaml file in a quarto file?
subtitle: Organization Template
footer: Organization Footer
logo: logo.png
filters: filters.lua
format: revealjs


Make a _quarto.yml file that contains this information. The file needs to be in the same project as the quarto file. If something more complex is needed, I recommend making a Quarto extension.
.
